# If the average of 2 successive years’ production 1/2($a_n + a_{n-1}$) is 2n + 5 and $a_0=3$, find $a_n$.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

If the average of 2 successive years’ production $\frac{1}{2}(a_n + a_{n-1})$ is $2n + 5$ and $a_0=3$, find $a_n$.
I started by solving for $a_n$ and got:
$a_n = 4n+10-a_{n-1}$ but I am unsure how to finish the problem.

Comment: If you don't have any better ideas, a reasonable next step is to calculate some values.  A spreadsheet makes this easy with copy down.  In this case it jumps out that $a_{4k-3}=a_{4k}=8k+3$ with $a_{4k-2}=8k-1, a_{4k-1}=8k=7$  That becomes a target for induction.

Comment: Any ideas on how to solve it by converting it to a homogeneous recurrence relation?

Comment: I would write $b_n=a_n+cn+d$, substitute in, and find $c,d$ to give $b_n=-b_{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-homogeneous linear recurrence equation where the non-homogeneous part is a polynomial. There are general methods to solve such recurrences but your specific example can be simplified.

To solve the recurrence relation

$$ \begin{cases}
a_0 = 3 \\
a_n = 4n - 10 - a_{n-1}
\end{cases} $$

First notice that $a_1 = -9$. One can try to expand the recurrence one term further:

$$ a_{n+2} = 4(n+2) - 10 - a_{n+1} = 4(n+2) - 10 - (4(n+1) - 10 - a_{n}) $$
$$ a_{n+2} = 4n + 8 - 10 - 4n - 4 + a_{n} = a_{n} + 4 $$

Therefore we have
$$ a_{2k} = a_0 + 4k = 3 + 2(2k) $$
$$ a_{2k+1} = a_1 + 4k = -11 + 2(2k+1)$$

Combining them, we have $a_n = 2n -4 + 7(-1)^n$.